# URI rerouting issue in codeigniter (version 2.2.0)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am struggle with URI rerouting in my codeigniter version(2.2.0)application.

Here is my routes.php

```
$route['details/(:num)'] = 'agent/manage_agents/$1';
```

And in my view file

```
foreach($data as $value) {?>

<a href="<?php base_url();?>details/<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Manage</a>
}?>
```

But i will get 404 error.

In my Controller file

```
class Agent extends CI_Controller {

   public function manage_agents($id)
    {
        echo $id;
    }   
}
```

**UPDATE**

Finally i found Which causes the problem.In my routes.php

```
$route['(:any)'] = "spotmyticket/$1";
```

when hide this line everything works  fine.
Here is my complete routes.php

```
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['default_controller'] = "spotmyticket";
$route['ticket']="ticket";
$route['ticket/(:any)'] = $route['ticket'].'/$1';

$route['captcha'] = "captcha"; 
$route['captcha/(:any)'] = "captcha/$1";
$route['admin'] = "admin"; 
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/$1";
$route['userdashboard'] = "userdashboard";
$route['userdashboard/(:any)'] = "userdashboard/$1"; 
$route['fbci'] = "fbci"; 
$route['fbci/(:any)'] = "fbci/$1";

$route['(:any)'] = "spotmyticket/$1";

$route['agent-management'] = 'agent/index';
$route['register'] = "agent/agent_register";
$route['test'] = 'agent/test';
$route['details/(:any)'] = 'agent/manage_agents/$1';
```

Here `spotmyticket` is the default controller of my site

Comment: Place this at the end of file: $route['(:any)'] = "spotmyticket/$1";

Comment: Rocking it works thanks dude

Comment: From docs: `Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this line at the end of file. $route['(:any)'] its breaking the execution of your other routing rules.

```
$route['(:any)'] = "spotmyticket/$1";
```

Comment: Yeah its worked any way i'll wait 6 minutes to accept the answer